# ng-table pagination not working

Tags: javascript, ngtable

Here is the situation, I have the following:
- An input field, in which I enter a username with ng-model='user_name'.
- A button, with ng-click="queryUserLogs(user_name, $event)
- When I input a username, and click on the button, the following method which is defined in my controller is invoked:

```
// un: username
$scope.queryUserLogs = function(un, $event){
    if(typeof $scope.user_name !== 'undefined'){
        var transaction_id = gen_uuid();
        $scope.$watch("user_name", function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if($event.type === "click"){
                console.log("Reloading...");
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
                delete $event.type;
            }
        });
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
        }, {
            total: 0,
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                BI.get({userName: $scope.user_name, page: params.page(), count: params.count()}, function(data) {
                    // set new data
                    $scope.basicInfos = data.results;
                    params.total(data.count);
                    $scope.showLogs = true;
                    $defer.resolve(data.results.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                });
            },
            $scope: { $data: {} }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Username is empty!");
    }
}
```

- For the first request, the method is invoked normally, goes to the server using the BI $resource and gets the data and displays it right. Everything works just fine.
- When I change the username, and click on the button the following error appears in the console:

  ```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at http://localhost:8000/static/js/ng-table.min.js:414:33
      at u (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:97:280)
      at http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:98:417
      at h.$eval (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:108:482)
      at h.$digest (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:106:62)
      at h.$apply (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:109:287)
      at f (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:71:247)
      at F (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:75:408)
      at XMLHttpRequest.x.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8000/static/js/angular.min.js:76:457)
  ```
- The new data actually is retrieved successfully, but the pagination stops working that if the first queried username has say 4 pages, and the second has only one page, the pagination stays as 4 pages in the second query and vice verse.

PS: The ngTable is added to the controller dependencies .

Comment: Don't know if it is the problem but you should not register the watch in the click-handler. Instead use a flag which signals the watch if it should do something or nor.

Comment: Why fiddle with the `event`?

Comment: Try using `angular.js`, the not minified code, to get a clue what the `TypeErrpr` could mean.

Comment: @phylax I used the unmodified version, here is the error log:
http://pastebin.com/PsJbKWL3
I changed it to watch the $event but it gave the same error.

Comment: See this link to fix your code - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1267 You will see that you should not bind to primitives as strange things can happen. Fix this first, then we'll keep troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use #ngTasty table pagination?

It's way easier.

http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table